# Cannot edit answers from review queues

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues, edits

I was trying to edit an answer from the review queues *[Late answers](https://stackoverflow.com/review)* and *[First answers](https://stackoverflow.com/review)*. It allows me to edit, but I can not save the edited answer. It doesn't show any message or any error for that. I don't have any pending edit suggestions either.

[image]

Comment: It's odd that there's no message. Suggested edits queue looks to be sitting at 496 pending edits so it's possible the queue is full, but it should still give and indication if that were the issue...

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`), read any errors. Also check the Network tab: what does the Response of the request say when clicking “Save edits”? Which browser are you using? Make sure it’s [supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161/289905). Possibly related: [The “save edits” button is non-functional](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376879/289905).

Comment: I tried to edit few times before. It is working like this for me.

Comment: @SebastianSimon I am using Chrome. I tried with F12 console. There is not any error or other information

Comment: @DaminiSuthar Which version of Chrome? Have you checked the Network tab?

Comment: Version 99.0.4844.51 of Chrome , Nothing failing in network tab

Comment: @DaminiSuthar Does it work with all extensions and userscripts disabled? I don’t know why the edit summary has a blue background in your screenshot… I can’t reproduce this in Firefox Nightly 99.0a1 so far.

Comment: The background of an input field in Chrome is blue if an autocomplete option was selected @SebastianSimon

Comment: Whoopsie wednesday strikes again

Comment: I do hope that this edit summary was just a placeholder for this meta post and that you don't actually use it. In the small off-chance that you do actually use that as a summary - ***please don't!*** We all know that you edited the answer. The point of the summary is to explain what and why you edited. I would be very glad if that was the reason you couldn't post the edit...

Comment: I was tring to edit answer as we edit question.

Comment: I'm having the same issue on the First Questions queue. The "Save edits" button registers the click, makes a POST request, but ultimately does nothing. I'm using Chrome.

Comment: @muad-dweeb What does the response of the POST request say?

Comment: @SebastianSimon I can't say, it eventually began working. I'll add to this if the problem reoccurs.

Comment: @muad-dweeb is it working for you now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for tackling review queues and the report!

There was an issue where error message popups were not being shown.  Nothing was logged to the console because we weren't throwing an exception, but just reporting back a status message.  The action was cancelled, but the error never displayed.

This particular workflow occurred with:

1. Having a full review queue of suggested edits (>500 suggestions)
2. Having someone who has permission to queues (>500 rep)
3. Having someone who only has permission to suggest edits (<2000 rep)

This should "work" now, in that at least it will give you the proper error message to explain what's going on

[image: suggested edit queue is full]

De-burdening the review queues is a story for another day.

Comment: Thank you..!! Yes it was not working before but now it is working.

Comment: 1) What is the argument for leaving out the article? 2) Why not plural ("[Suggested edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/31309545)")? (Not rhetorical questions; I am not disputing any of it.)

Comment: (However, it *is* [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance), not StackOverflow.)

Comment: @PeterMortensen, can you elaborate on what you're asking about?  Not sure I understand.

Comment: @KyleMit On the 2-year anniversary of this answer, the previously resolved issue has come back :D I just tried to edit something in the Late Answers review queue today, clicked "Edit," and nothing happened. So, I opened the question to see what was going on, and clicking "Edit" from the *question* page brought up the "queue is full" message.